# Find series of real functions for which the sum has continuity properties

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, convergence-divergence

The sequence of continuous real functions $f_i$
is defined on the unit interval $[0, 1]$.
Each $f_i$
is composed of finitely many linear segments, each segment
has slope +1 or −1, moreover $f =\sum f_i$
is convergent for every $x$.

a) Give a sequence $f_i$ such that $f$ has derivative everywhere in the unit
interval.

b) Give a sequence $f_i$ for which $f$ is not continuous at 1/2.

c) Give a sequence such that $f$ is not continuous at any point.

Any hints on  how to construct these sequences.

Comment: The $f_i$ are not supposed to be continuous?

Comment: yes they are continuous

Comment: Then I modified your question as this is important!

Comment: thank you @mathcounterexamples.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question a)**
Take $$\begin{array}{l|rcll}
f_1 : & [0,1] & \longrightarrow & [0,1] \\
    & x & \longmapsto & x & \text{ for } 0 \le x \le \frac{1}{2}\\
    & x & \longmapsto & 1-x & \text{ else }
\end{array},$$ $f_2=1-f_1$ and for $p \ge 0$
$$\begin{cases}
f_{2p+1}(x)=\frac{f_1(2^p x)}{2^p}\\
f_{2p+2}=\frac{1}{2^p}-f_{2p+1}
\end{cases}$$ You can verify that the sequence $(f_i)$ satisfy the requested conditions. Moreover $f_{2p+1}+f_{2p+2}=\frac{1}{2^p}$. Therefore $$f(x)=\sum f_i(x) = \sum_{p=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^p}=2$$ is constant and continuous.

Comment: I'm trying to find examples for the other questions. I suggest that you split your question in 3 questions. In that way the other members will not think that your question is completly answered.