# Find series of real functions for which the sum is discontinuous everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

The sequence of continuous real functions $f_i$ is defined on the unit interval $[0, 1]$.
Each $f_i$ is composed of finitely many linear segments, each segment
has slope +1 or −1, moreover $f =\sum f_i$ is convergent for every $x$.

Give a sequence such that $f$ is not continuous at any point.

The question was raised in the post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1550042/find-series-of-real-functions-for-which-the-sum-has-continuity-properties) among other questions.

Comment: There is no such example even if you drop the piecewise linear requirement, which seems to be present just to add an element of mystery to the problem.  (Look up what a Baire one function is.)

Comment: The theorem to quote is that a pointwise limit of a sequence of continuous functions cannot be discontinuous everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, such an example cannot be found as the pointwise limit of a sequence of continuous functions is continuous in a dense set according to a [theorem of Baire.](https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_de_la_limite_simple_de_Baire)